# Manipulating a non-evenly spaced data series in python

Tags: python, scipy

Hello guys I've trying to plot a bunch of data of some measurements taken in uneven intervals of time  and make a cubic spline interpolation of it. Here is a sample of the data:

1645 2 28 .0

1645 6 30 .0

1646 6 30 .0

1646 7 31 .0

The first column corresponds to the year which the measurement was made, the second column is the month, the third one is the number of measurements and the fourth one is the standard deviation of the measurements.

The thing is that I can't seem to figure out how to make a scatter plot of the data keeping the "unevenness" of the intervals of measurement. Also I'm not quite sure how to implement the interpolation cause I don't know what should be my x value for the data points (months maybe?)

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Btw I'm working with python and using Scipy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For x, you could either convert the year and month to a `datetime` object:

```
np.datetime64('2005-02')
```

Or convert it to months (assuming 1645 is your first value):

```
CumulativeMonth = (year - 1645) * 12 + month
```